# Strange behaviour of QueryString query with AND operator

Tags: elasticsearch

A query:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/customer/doc/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "\"&\""
        }
    }
}
'
```

returns no hits. That is okay.

But the following query:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/customer/doc/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "\"&\" AND Jane"
        }
    }
}
'
```

returns hits for 'Jane'.

Is this a bug? Who can explain this behaviour?

Test Data can be created with:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/customer/doc/1?pretty&pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "name": "Jane Doe"
}
'
```

ElasticSearch version is 5.4.1